# Performance Issue - Join/Index

Tags: performance, join, indexing

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM jmr_bbi_dife_vendas_neg2 dife
         WHERE     dife.processado = 'N'
               AND dife.removido = 'N'
               AND dife.revertido = 'N'
               AND TO_DATE(LPAD(dife.DAY, 2, '0') || LPAD(dife.MONTH, 2, '0') || dife.YEAR, 'DDMMYYYY') <= to_date('20160331','YYYYMMDD')
       ) dife
       LEFT JOIN jmr_bbi_dade_vendas dade
           ON     dade.codins = 1
              AND dade.codneg = 2
              AND dade.tipdoc_vnd = dife.doc_type
              AND dade.numdoc_vnd = dife.doc_no
              AND dade.codart = dife.item
              AND dade.anoper = dife.year
              AND dade.mesper = dife.month;
```

and i create index on DADE.
[Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5bjt.jpg)

But when i execute the explain plan on this query, the index is not used:

[Explain Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BExbs.jpg)

I already execute the gather statistics of full table, but don't work either.

Can help me please?

This two tables: DIFE and DADE are 2 tables example.
My original table of each other have millions of rows.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create index on columns of both table which are being used in join-condition.

Also move `dade.codins = 1 AND dade.codneg = 2` into where condition

Comment: Awesome mate!
Gonna try on the tables with million rows to see the results! :)

Comment: Well mate... Don't work! :(

If i put the query as you said, it don't return any results.... :(

Comment: Any idea more? :(